# Getting an ID inside a PostgreSQL transaction block

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I'm trying to wrap all my transactions that should be all-or-nothing into `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`, but I'm not sure how to do this in cases like the following.

I have 3 tables, one for images, one for `albums`, and one for the relations between them, namely `album_images`. The way the system works is that a user can create an album and fill it with his images in one operation. The SQL is as follows:

```
BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO albums [...];  -- Create a new album row
  SELECT id AS album_id FROM albums WHERE [...];  -- Get that rows ID
  -- Now use album_id in the next statement
  INSERT INTO album_images (album_id, image_id) [...];
COMMIT;
```

This is probably a common problem, I'm just not sure what to search for and I can't seem to find a solution in the documentation either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an alternative to the INSERT ... RETURNING clause mentioned by Cody, you can use the current value the sequence associated with the ID column:

```
BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO albums [...];
  INSERT INTO album_images (currval('albums_id_seq'), image_id) [...];
COMMIT;
```

This assumes the standard naming scheme from Postgres when creating the sequence automatically for columns defined as `serial`.

Another alternative - if you are only using a single insert - is to use the `lastval()` function. You would then not even need to put the sequence name into the INSERT statement:

```
BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO albums [...];
  INSERT INTO album_images (lastval(), image_id) [...];
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Hm, both examples produce `syntax error at or near "("` for me. Even if one of these will work eventually, I take it there is no way of using the value from `album_id` from my `SELECT`?

Comment: Is `lastval` specific to the transaction, or could it be altered by another concurrent transaction?

Comment: It's specific to the _connection_ (=session)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so it could return the wrong value if another (sharing the connection) inserted concurrently

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi: your assumption is wrong. Using `lastval()` directly after an INSERT **is** safe, just as using `currval()` is. If you have an application where it's possible that some code does an insert and another part does a different insert using the same physical connect before the first transaction gets to call `lastval()` then I would argue that your code is broken. But even in that situation `currval()` would be safe assuming that both inserts use different tables.

Comment: Lets say two users sign up to your website at the exact same time, couldn't their transactions be intertwined - leading to corrupted insertions due to the race condition?

Comment: Those two transactions would use two different physical connections. You can't have two parallel independent transactions on a single physical connection

Comment: So, `lastval()` is effectively specific to the transaction (as only one transaction can run per connection)?

Comment: No, it's specific to the session. It always returns the last value generated by any sequence. If you have ten inserts into ten tables, lastval will return the one from the final insert. Please read the manual, it's all explained there

Comment: So this isn't robust then, as it could return the wrong value...

Comment: If **is** robust if you use it correctly. This is like saying "DELETE isn't robust because it could delete the wrong row"

Comment: What we want to do is select the specific id just inserted. lastval is a hacky implementation of this, and is prone to error - simply by having another concurrent insert... That's why I say this is not robust. The solution I posted is not prone to that issue, and additionally works more logically: `var a_id = insert_a(...); insert_a_b(a_id, ...)` as opposed to `insert_a(...); insert_a_b(get_the_id_of_the_last_thing_inserted_on_this_connection(), ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Manually accessing sequences is not ideal

```sql
BEGIN;
  -- Create a new album row and hold onto the id
  WITH row as (INSERT INTO albums [...] RETURNING id AS album_id)
  -- Now use album_id in the next insert
  INSERT INTO album_images SELECT album_id, :image_id FROM row;
COMMIT;
```

`returning` was actually useful, however, the other 2 answers didn't know/explain how to apply it here

Comment: "*Manually accessing sequences is not a robust solution"* - yes it is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name changed my verbiage

Comment: You need to at least remove the `;` after the CTE to make that a correct statement.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres provides a "RETURNING" clause used in an INSERT to easily get back the newly-created primary key.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-insert.html

Some examples: http://6c62.net/blog/?p=48

Comment: Thanks, but my problem isn't so much with getting that ID, but with using it in the next statement. That `SELECT` in my example is actual working code that will return the correct ID. Or did I misunderstand something? Those examples are a little over my head.

Comment: When i try to use a named RETURNING inside another statement of the transaction it throw an "unknow column"  errror... I dont think that thoses variables are shared within the transaction.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the id of the inserted row as

```
INSERT INTO albums [...] returning album_id;
```

This will return the album_id after insertion.

Comment: Specifically, the OP want's to use the `id` in the next statement in the transaction. `RETURNING` clause does not solve this independently.