# Execute Postgresql function that accepts an array of parameters using pg-promise

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, pg-promise

We have this postgresql type:

```
create type order_input as (
    item text,
    quantity integer);
```

And this postgresql function:

```
create or replace function insert_into_orders(order_input[])
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare 
    inserted_id integer;
begin
    insert into public.orders(orderdate) 
    values (now()) 
    returning orderid into inserted_id;

    insert into public.orderdetails(orderid, item, quantity)
    select inserted_id, item, quantity
    from unnest($1);
end $$;
```

To execute in pgadmin-4 we run:

```
select insert_into_orders(
    array[
        ('Red Widget', 10), 
        ('Blue Widget', 5)
    ]::order_input[]
);
```

I am trying to figure out how to execute the insert_into_orders function using the pg-promise javascript library. I've tried doing the following:

```
const pgp = require("pg-promise")();
const db = pgp(connectionObj);

await db.func("insert_into_orders", [{item:"Red Widget", quantity:10}, {item:"Blue Widget", quantity:5}]
```

but getting the following message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "malformed array literal: \"{\"item\":\"Red Widget\", \"quantity\":10}\""
  }
}
```

Would really appreciate if anyone knew how I had to structure my input for pg-promise, the original post is from here: [Postgres Function to insert multiple records in two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604808/postgres-function-to-insert-multiple-records-in-two-tables?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [func](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#func) expects an array of values as the second parameter. In your case it must be one parameter - array of objects. But you instead give it 2 parameters, each an object, hence the error.

The correct way is:

```js
const orderInput = [{item:"Red Widget", quantity:10}, {item:"Blue Widget", quantity:5}];

await db.func('insert_into_orders', [orderInput]);
```

Anyhow, you should use event [query](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query) or [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor) to see what SQL was generated.

Also, your `insert_into_orders` should be a [stored procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html), and then executed via [proc](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#proc), at the very least. However, its implementation looks like it should be just a transaction within your code.

> After this executed the error came back as `"error": {"message": "function insert_into_orders(text[]) does not exist"}`

That's because of the type mismatch, which requires type casting...

You can either invoke the function via a regular query method, or make use of [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting) to modify the data format:

```
const data = {
    toPostgres: () => `${pgp.as.array(orderInput)}::json[]::order_input[]`,
    rawType: true
};
```

Then pass it in instead:

```
await db.func('insert_into_orders', [data]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, they were extremely useful! I added the event query and the executed query that got generated was `select * from insert_into_orders(array[('Red Widget', 10), ('Blue Widget', 5)])`. After this executed the error came back as `{
  "error": {
    "message": "function insert_into_orders(text[]) does not exist"
  }
}` as this postgresql function is expecting `insert_into_orders(order_input[])`. Do you know if there is a way to map the input data to this `order_input type`? This is also for learning purposes, but I agree with your stored proc & transaction suggestion.

Comment: I tried the updated solution you proposed which gave me the following query 
`select * from insert_into_orders
(array['{"item":"Red Widget","quantity”:10}’]::thought_input[])`

but I got the 

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "malformed array literal: \"{\"item\":\"Red Widget\", \"quantity\":10}\""
  }
}` 

error again. I wonder if it is because the sql function is expecting the data to be a tuple of list? Any thoughts?

Comment: @Gus Try an extra cast maybe? Like `::json[]::order_input[]`

Comment: unfortunately I could not get the casting from an object to a tuple to work. I simply used string interpolation to make the orderInput look like a tuple `('Red Widget', 10), ('Blue Widget', 5)` since that is what the function was expecting and kept all of your other suggestions. I really appreciate all the help. Don't know who you are but stay safe and healthy man.

Comment: @Gus WHat error are you getting when using `::json[]::order_input[]` type casting? It should work, I think. I have updated the answer with that type casting. Try it ;) Oh, and I am the author of pg-promise :)

Comment: sorry for the delay, things have been crazy. I am getting a `cannot cast type json[] to order_input[]` error. Here is the query that was generated `select * from insert_into_orders( array[ '{"item":"Red Widget","quantity":1}', '{"item":"Blue Widget","quantity":2}']::json[]::order_input[])`. Also that is awesome, pg-promise is a game changer haha. Would love to read about your story, any blogs?? Hope you are well and healthy brother.

Comment: To simplify debugging I ran the following directly in pgAdmin 4 

`create type order_input as (
    item text,
    quantity integer);`

`create or replace function insert_into_orders(order_input[])
returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
    select *
    from unnest($1);
end $$;`

`select * from insert_into_orders( array[ '{"item":"Red Widget","quantity":1}', '{"item":"Blue Widget","quantity":2}']::json[]::order_input[])`

Comment: I also think the extra apostrophe marks surrounding the array of objects (i.e. '{"item":"Red Widget","quantity":1}') will cause insert issues if the value of the item has an apostrophe itself like "Red's widget" or "haven't widget". Thoughts?

Comment: is there a way to directly message you? I looks like the following characters may be one of the reason's inserting multiple records into a postgres function using pg-promise: single quote, double qoute, and comma. Sorry to keep commenting on the thread

Comment: Like @Gus, couldn't get it to work with the json[] cast, but just using vitaly's ``values`` helper inside an ``array[...]`` to create the tuples, then casting to the param array type worked. So replacing with ``toPostgres: () => `array[${this.pgp.helpers.values(orderInput, ["item", "quantity"])}]::order_input[]` ``

Comment: @vitaly-t This is working great, but quick question - If I call this as `CALL my_proc($1)` and pass the formatted array as the value, it replaces the $1, effectively inlining the array instead of sending it as a parameter. Is there any easy way to make it keep the $1 and send the array as the $1 param? Makes no difference functionally, but AWS collects performance statistics on distinct SQL statements, and with the array inlined, it considers each call a different statement because the array values are different.

Comment: @reads0520 For that you cannot use the `func`/`proc` - those are just formatting helpers for simple cases. Instead, use `PreparedStatement` for the function call, passing it parameters.

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks, unfortunately can't seem to find any way to format the array of tuples that works sending as a parameter. Everything I've tried results in "malformed array literal" error.